# Network Error (dns_server_failure)

Tags: web-application, host-header

Hi created a sharepoint web application and I assigned a host name. I created it both ways, via the UI and via powershell script.
I added the host name in the host file. Last week it was working just fine, but today, I am getting the following error:

```
Network Error (dns_server_failure) 

Your request could not be processed because an error occurred contacting the DNS server.  
The DNS server may be temporarily unavailable, or there could be a network problem.  

Transaction ID: b4a4b862d5c9113c-0000000005dc3c84-000000005dada0d5
```

Edit: I am not using any DNS, it is everything local. The only thing is that the Sql server is in another server. I don't think it is an sql server issue, because the other web application is working just fine. The only difference is that the second web application does not have a host-header.

Any idea how to tackle this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using a proxy and that caused the error. So, check if you have a proxy in your internet explorer and remove it. 
This is when you are using the host file as dns.

Comment: You can mark your own answer as the correct one. And you should.